# "Error: DEP 0700: Registration of the app failed" when importing Unity project into Visual Studio

Tags: c#, x86, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2013

I have a Unity project set up for Windows Store applications. I need to import that project into the VS2013 Pro edition.

So far, I have imported the project into VS, but it gives me an error

> Error: DEP 0700: Registration of the app failed. Windows cannot install package Sample assets project because the package require architecture ARM, but this windows has x86.

I am not sure if my windows is wrong (I have version 8.1 ). What causes this error and how can I resolve it?

Comment: I heavily recommend to post your question in the unity subforum http://forum.unity3d.com/forums/50-Windows-Development as your question will be exposed to more people with the knowledge you are seeking. Unfortunately I have never published a Unity project to windows (other than the basic desktop build)

Comment: Thanks, will post it there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to the fact that (as the error states) the development machine does not have an ARM architecture, but an x86 one. By default Unity will export a project for both configurations, and it might default to the ARM setting.

To change this, you'll have to open the [Configuration Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwybya3w.aspx). In there, you will find that the Active Solution Platform is set to ARM. From the dropdown select the platform to one that works for your system, which is probably x86.

With that done you should normally be able to run your application.